# database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); Error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create an application with `Firebase` but when i open app it stops.

These my dependencies;

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my main activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
users = database.getReference("Users");

edtUser=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUser);
edtPassword=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
```

when app crashes i look logcat and says that

**database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); error line**

How can i fix this? Can you please help me?

Crash logs

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.cagri.kpssgenelkltrtesti-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.example.cagri.kpssgenelkltrtesti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at 
>      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   07-20 12:30:25.004 8100-8145/com.example.cagri.kpssgenelkltrtesti E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
>   07-20 12:30:37.529 8100-8100/com.example.cagri.kpssgenelkltrtesti I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8100 SIG: 9

Comment: Can you please attach crash logs

Comment: I did. Please see the question again

Comment: Have you followed this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
Maybe you've skipped something!
the root cause is that you most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing incompatible versions of Firebase SDKs in your project. Make sure that all versions are <16 or all versions are >= 16. E.g.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

When you have this type of problem, I recommend checking out the [Firebase documentation on getting started on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries).